# What is the best way to implement application level acknowledgement to the broker in mqtt?

Tags: mqtt, esp32

I am using esp32 mqtt client library. In this, whenever a valid mqtt message is received with QoS1, mqtt_client library sends a Puback message automatically without waiting for application layer to authenticate the payload. There are two ways to overcome this situation -

1. Holding Puback message untill application layer process it
2. Opening a new topic between client and broker to implement application level authentication mechanism?

Could you guys please suggest the best approach ?

Comment: There is no publisher to subscriber or subscriber to publisher delivery notification in MQTT even at QOS 1 or 2. The acknowledgements are only ever between 1 client and the broker. If you want end to end acknowledgement then you have to send a second message.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right behavior because the ack is at protocol level. Holding PUBACK, if the MQTT library you are using allows doing that is not the right thing to do imho because you break somehow the contract at protocol level and if the application spends too much time processing the message without sending the PUBACK, the broker will resend the message not receiving the PUBACK on time.
Imho the best solution is relying on a different topic on which the client publish an "ack at application level".

Answer (score 0):

Puback ack packet is being sent without validation from Application level because that's how it is supposed to work. Quality of Service (QoS) factor in MQTT doesn't mean that ack packet is sent when data content in packet is validated. It is meant to acknowledge the reception. That's all.

For what you are trying to do, you need to implement an application level protocol to serve or discard the packets after validating the data (and then notify the sender with another packet).